# watir: content of frame.body is not updated (is there any refresh method)

Tags: phantomjs, watir

Hi I am using watir for cucumber test of PHP project.
Unfortunately page is always make from two frames.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
    <title>Rothschild - Olomouc</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skripty.js"></script>
  </head>
  <frameset cols="183,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="*">
    <frame name="leftFrame" scrolling="AUTO" noresize src="">
    <frame name="mainFrame" src="getuser.php">
  </frameset>
  <noframes> 
    <body id=body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    </body>
  </noframes> 
</html>
```

`leftFrame` is menu, 
`mainFrame` is main page content.

I use

```
if headless
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs #headless  
else
  require 'watir-webdriver'
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie #non headless,IExplorer
end

main_content= @browser.frame(:name, "mainFrame").body
```

to get content of main part of page.
 It works almost every time.

But now I get to situation when doubleclicking on `TR`

```
  <tr class="subTable dealer_1" onDblClick="window.location.href='detail_dealer.php?id=207'">
    <td><a name="a207"></a></td>
    <td>    Lama Mirek</td>
    <td> Ústí n. Orlicí</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

get me to page `detail_dealer.php?id=207` (in `mainFrame` of course)
but

@browser.frame(:name, "mainFrame").body

gives me previous table (with doubleclicking rows).

When I try to debug it with PRY

```
pry:> @browser.frame(:name, "mainFrame").body  => content of desired detail page
```

It looks like watir needs a time to "reload" content of body. Is there some method to do "`refresh`" or "`wait until new content is loaded`"?

This happens with both drivers `watir-webdriver` and `phantomjs`.

Answer (score 0):

Watir has a number of [methods for waiting](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/).

You will need find an element that only exists after clicking on the `tr` element. Then call one of the wait methods. For example:

```
browser.element.wait_until_present
```

Alternatively, you can also wait for an element to be removed after the `tr` is clicked:

```
browser.element.wait_while_present
```